# Using EWS SOAP requests in an Outlook web add-in

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, office-addins

I need to use several EWS requests (e.g. `GetUserConfiguration`, `UpdateUserConfiguration`) that are not supported using `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`.

I cannot use the EWS Managed API in my own web service as a broker, and must use XML SOAP requests directly from the add-in's JavaScript (those methods are not available in the Graph or Mail APIs).

There are many examples (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/call-a-service-by-using-an-identity-token)) showing how `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` can be used to pass that token to your web service (again, which I can't use) to use there in whatever way you need it.

However, I'm guessing the token retrieved from `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` is different and cannot be used.  As a simple and hopefully appropriate test, I obtained an OAUTH token for my O365 account and used that as the token using [SOAPe](https://soape.codeplex.com/) for a test `GetUserConfiguratio`n call and it worked. I then tried using the token from `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` and it didn't work (`401 Unauthorized`).

I concede that this may be a poor test, and I admit that at this point it is unclear to me how a SOAP EWS request from JavaScript in an Outlook dd-in can be authenticated without requiring an explicit user login (hopefully it can). And if it can, how do I get the token I need and how do I use it for this kind of client-side request?

Comment: As a workaround the userconfiguration objects are just FAI objects in the folder, so you may be able to just use FindItems, GetItem and UpdateItem to just update the underlying extended properties for the user configuration object.

Comment: Good idea, thanks Glen! I've already got to the point of getting IPM.Configuration.OWA.UserOptions from GetItem, but am currently at a loss of how to include the DictionaryEntry values in the response (e.g. signaturehtml and it's value).

Comment: Its just a serialized XML documented https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765806.aspx eg just convert the XML to a byte array and post it into the PR_Roaming_Dictionary property. (you need to get the existing value first and then append into that).

Comment: Perfect! For those of you playing the home game, you'd want: <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="31751" PropertyType="Binary" />, then decode the value

Comment: For getUserIdentityTokenAsync, you are correct that this token can't be used to make EWS requests. Currently, the user would have to authenticate a second time with OAuth in order to make EWS or REST API requests from an add-in's backend service. Glad you were able to get your scenario working with makeEwsRequestAsync.

Comment: But this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/call-a-service-by-using-an-identity-token) suggests that a token *can* be used in a back-end service, and I'm assuming without a second login. Note though that for my scenario I cannot use a back-end web service and it most be all code in the add-in

Comment: You can request two kinds of token from getCallbackTokenAsync - EWS and REST. Then using those tokens you can work either with EWS service or Rest Service. REST is a more preferred way and you should be able to accomplish your scenario using that. Find documentation for getCallbackTokenAsync here: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook

Comment: BTW @GlenScales, it turns out that updating an FAI from within an Outlook web add-in is not supported, much to my horror. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739744/cant-use-ews-updateitem-operation-from-outlook-add-in

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use ews-javascript-api helper in this case. here is the example on how to use this with Outlook Add-ins.
https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser#working-with-plain-jsts-no-module-loadersbundlers

you may use any allowed api (available in makeEwsRequestAsync) with this library. with similar api what is available in Ews managed Api.

Comment: Interesting - not sure how I missed this! I'll try to take a look, but I may never now as this project is over lol