# Can't use EWS UpdateItem operation from Outlook add-in

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm am trying to update a dictionary element in the `IPM.Configuration.OWA.UserOptions` message using an `UpdateItem` via an EWS (SOAP) request from an Outlook web add-in with `ReadWriteMailbox` permissions. However it is failing with the following error in the response:

```
ErrorAccessDenied: Office extension is not allowed to update this type of item.
```

The UpdateItem request I'm using is a fairly straightforward example of updating a message by it's ID and setting the value of an extended property:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite">
      <m:ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGM0YTZmNjhiLTI0OWYtNGFlNC05ODAzLTNlZWQyODhmOTY2MABGAAAAAACxU7lpjO+oS5hB0UfA6muFBwDcAGmTk49MRrSCdR7rvVFPAAAAAAEBAADcAGmTk49MRrSCdR7rvVFPAAD2pXuVAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAADcAGmTk49MRrSCdR7rvVFPAAD2uhNb" />
          <t:Updates>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x7c07" PropertyType="Binary" />
              <t:Message>
                <t:ExtendedProperty>
                    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x7c07" PropertyType="Binary" />
                    <t:Value>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</t:Value>
                </t:ExtendedProperty>                
              </t:Message>
            </t:SetItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </m:ItemChanges>
    </m:UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The 0x7c07 property I'm updating in the UserOptions message contains a base64 encoded value of various signature related dictionary properties that I've modified:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserConfiguration>
    <Info version="Exchange.12" />
    <Data>
        <e k="18-IsFocusedInboxOnLastUpdateTime" v="18-01/01/0001 00:00:00" />
        <e k="18-autoaddsignature" v="3-True" />
        <e k="18-UserOptionsMigrationState" v="9-5" />
        <e k="18-themeStorageId" v="18-" />
        <e k="18-autoaddsignatureonreply" v="3-True" />
        <e k="18-timezone" v="18-Central Standard Time" />
        <e k="18-signaturetext" v="18-&#xD;&#xA;--&#xD;&#xA;Izzz am Janick&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" />
        <e k="18-FavoriteFolders" v="1-18-3-120-AAMkAGM0YTZmNjhiLTI0OWYtNGFlNC05ODAzLTNlZWQyODhmOTY2MAAuAAAAAACxU7lpjO+oS5hB0UfA6muFAQDcAGmTk49MRrSCdR7rvVFPAAAAAAEMAAA=-120-AAMkAGM0YTZmNjhiLTI0OWYtNGFlNC05ODAzLTNlZWQyODhmOTY2MAAuAAAAAACxU7lpjO+oS5hB0UfA6muFAQDcAGmTk49MRrSCdR7rvVFPAAAAAAEJAAA=-120-AAMkAGM0YTZmNjhiLTI0OWYtNGFlNC05ODAzLTNlZWQyODhmOTY2MAAuAAAAAACxU7lpjO+oS5hB0UfA6muFAQDcAGmTk49MRrSCdR7rvVFPAAAAAAEPAAA=" />
        <e k="18-IsOptimizedForAccessibility" v="3-False" />
        <e k="18-IsFocusedInboxEnabled" v="3-True" />
        <e k="18-NewEnabledPonts" v="9-2147401727" />
        <e k="18-signaturehtml" v="18-&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;--&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;John Doe&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;;" />
    </Data>
</UserConfiguration>
```

I can't find any documentation that states what is allowed or not allowed with `UpdateItem` operations ([the list should be here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions)). Updating the Outlook Online signature is also not currently possible with Graph or the Mail API.  If what I'm trying to do ultimately cannot work then I just wasted 40+ hours of effort and will lose a client. :-|

Does anybody have any clever workarounds or know of a way to enable this operation?  Note that using the EWS Managed API in server-side code is not currently an option for this solution.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish (i.e. what are you changing in UserOptions) and some sample code for how you're calling UpdateItem?

Comment: I'm basically just trying to update the OWA signature. I've added my SOAP requests to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook does not allow add-ins to create or update FAI messages by design. In general we don't allow modifications of OWA options (or any other “service-type”, internal, item/data) directly which is probably an internal data structure, subject to change and potentially break the add-in.

If your scenario specifically requires access to outlook's signature system, I would recommend making a request to [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins)

Comment: Would this action still be blocked if I used an auth token passed to a backend web service that uses the EWS Managed API to update the user's OWA signature? That API directly allows updating FAI messages

Comment: I'm fairly sure that attempting the call from the backend will not work either, and should result in the same error.

Comment: Will it fail because the authentication is coming from an add-in? There are examples of successfully using EWS with the UpdateUserConfiguration operation (see http://gsexdev.blogspot.ca/2009/12/changing-owa-configuration-setting-with.html), which was specifically introduced to allow modifying things like signatures (albeit at your own risk).

Comment: Me again - hope somebody there can still help me with this. I was previously able to set this signature using the EWS Managed API and Basic Auth in an ASP.NET Web API. When I try to use OAuthCredentials it works if I call the Web API from a local .NET client app, but it fails (unauthorized) if it's an Outlook web add-in getting the OAuth access token and passing it to the Web API to set the sig. Does the caller's client type matter??